# Is the APIClient created by ApacheAPIClientBuilder for Algolia Java threadsafe?

Tags: java, algolia

When using the APIClient created by ApacheAPIClientBuilder, is the APIClient thread-safe, or should a new one be created for each thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APIClient is not thread safe. It keeps an internal state that is not made to be thread safe.